# Thymeleaf - How to display text not included in th:text

Tags: java, html, spring, thymeleaf

I would like to display the name of a user using thymeleaf. Here is the html tag that I'm using:

```
<h1 th:text="${username}"></h1>
```

I want it to display this: Hello, User

Given username is a string "User". I tried something like this:

```
<h1 th:text="${username}">Hello, </h1>
```

But it didn't work. How can I fix it?

Comment: Try `<h1 th:text="|Hello, ${username}|"></h1>` or `<h1 th:text="'Hello, ' + ${username}"></h1>`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
<h1 th:text="'Hello, ' + ${username}"></h1>
```

Source:
https://www.wimdeblauwe.com/blog/2021/01/11/string-concatenation-with-thymeleaf/

Answer (score 4):

I personally prefer to just use an additional tag.

```
<h1>Hello, <span th:text="${username}" /></h1>
```

or [literal substitution](https://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/tutorials/3.0/usingthymeleaf.html#literal-substitutions)

```
<h1 th:text="|Hello, ${username}|"></h1>
```

as quoting strings just adds more complexity.